Session variable isn't accessible by other Flask routes
I can't figure out why my session variables aren't transferring to other flask routes. I believe I have it set up properly, but I'm having a problem with this code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for, render_template, session
from flask_session import Session
import requests
import os
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

# Session setup
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
app.config.from_object(__name__)
Session(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    shop_origin = session.get('shop_origin', 'Shop Origin In Session Not Set')
    print("index shop_origin is equal to: %s" % shop_origin, flush=True)
    if not shop_origin:
        session['have_shop_info_in_session'] = False

    if 'have_shop_info_in_session' in session:
        print("have_shop_info_in_session is equal to: %s" % session['have_shop_info_in_session'], flush=True)

    if 'have_shop_info_in_session' in session and session['have_shop_info_in_session']:
        shop_info = session.get('shop_info', 'No Shop Info Found')
        return render_template('app_interface.html')
    else:
        return render_template('fetch_shop_info.html')


@app.route('/set_shop_info', methods=['POST'])
def set_shop_info():
    data = request.get_json()
    shop_origin = data.get('shopOrigin')
    if not shop_origin:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Shop origin not provided'}), 400

    session['shop_origin'] = shop_origin
    print("Loaded session shop_origin: %s" % session.get('shop_origin'), flush=True)
    session['have_shop_info_in_session'] = True  # Set the flag to true
    print("set_shop_info have_shop_info_in_session is equal to: %s" % session['have_shop_info_in_session'], flush=True)
    return jsonify({'status': 'success'}), 200

When this code runs, I get positive flags in the logs with Loaded session shop_origin: testing-store.myshopify.com and set_shop_info have_shop_info_in_session is equal to: True, but as soon as the Javascript from the fetch_shop_info.html redirects to the index flask route, the logs show index shop_origin is equal to: Shop Origin In Session Not Set.
Why is the variable not transferring to the other route in the session? Cookies are enabled in the browser.
EDIT: I tried running the code in a different browser and it seems to work fine, so the problem has to be my browser (Brave Browser). I have Brave Shields turned off for Shopify and I can see that the cookie SEEMS to be stored correctly by the browser. I'm still not sure what the problem is exactly but I'm a little bit closer to figuring out what it is.

The code works properly in Firefox, but not Brave browser, so the issue is with the browser. I have no idea what this code does, but this seems to make the code work by adding it towards the top of my code. Here's a link to where I found the solution.
app.config.update(SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE="None", SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True)

